# Query runs slower from live server than on local machine

Tags: mysql

I have a query which is called from an ASP.Net application. When running from my local machine it runs in about 0.1s. When I publish the application to the live server the same query takes > 40s.

Both code bases are EXACTLY the same and are targeting the exact same server. I have checked for any firewall issues and both my machine and the live server are on the same domain as the database server.

What could I have missed, what could possibly be slowing this query down so much?

EDIT: Illustration of current structure.

[image]

Comment: Was it cached in your dev env?

Comment: What do you mean by cached? If you mean were the results cached? No. They were not. It is not just a single query it is every query that is ran. None more spectacularly that the example above with a 40s increase in time, but all queries perform slower running from the live server.

Comment: I think you must configure a new machine and copy the configuration and data from live server. If still the query takes > 1 sec, the problem is not in server but with sql data or configuration.

Comment: I think you are missing the point, I may be wrong, but the sql database is the same database for both environments. The only difference is the machine which is sending the query. I have updated the question to reflect the general scenario.

Comment: Does the query always take ~40s to return? What language is the app written in? e.g. if it was asp.net then the compilation time could explain the delay. Or do you have other things like firewalls, etc, slowing things down?

Comment: Checking the Trace, it takes just over 43s each and every time the page is called. It is ASP.Net, but debugging through shows that the delay is in the execution of the MySQL query, not the compilation of the code. But seeing as the code is compiled before the publish, I don't see how this would be a problem. As said above, I have checked the firewall and don't see any problems there.

Comment: The code is compiled to MSIL but is then compiled by the JIT compiler at runtime. When you recycle the application pool everything is recompiled. But if it's consistently slow then this doesn't seem like the answer. Is the query retrieving a lot of data? And is the connection between the DB and the live server slow for some reason (contention?)

Comment: Yeah checking simply the ping shows that the ping from my local machine to DB server was <1ms, from live server to DB server was 20ms. I pointed to a replication DB server which had a low ping from the live server and it has reduced the time taken. Now to investigate why the connection is so slow between live server and DB server as pointing to the replication server is unmaintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Could this not be explained by the live server also hosting other applications / sites - ie the demand on machine resources? Just a thought...

Comment: The live server has 2 sites on it and both are pretty small and both have the issue of slow queries. Access to them is restricted so there is not that much activity on either site, certainly nothing that should slow queries down to this pace.

Comment: Networking problems between the App Server and the DB Server?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the comments to the question above. The connection between the app server and DB server is slow. Switching to a replication DB server works but is not sustainable, but now  the problem is finding the reason for the network issue.